# Get documents using find() method in couchdb-nano

Tags: node.js, typescript, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Since CouchDB doesn't have any collections, I added a custom `type`property to my entitys. Now I want to filter all entitys on that property, e.g. get all users by `{type:'user'}`. In the couchdb-doc I found a [method called 'find()'](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#db-find), which is also implemented in the nano typings, but have a lack of documentation in [couchdb-nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano). According to the definition, I wrote the follwing code:

```
class UserModel {
    type: string = 'User';
    name: string = '';
    mail: string = '';
}
let db = <nano.DocumentScope<UserModel>>nano("http://localhost:5984/testdb");
let query: nano.MangoQuery = { selector: { type: "User" } };
db.find(query, (cb:nano.Callback<nano.MangoResponse<UserModel>>) => {
    // How to get the results here? cb is a callback, but this doesn't make sense
});
```

It doesn't make sense to me that I get a callback. How can I get the results?

Tried using some kind of callback:

```
db.find(query, (users: nano.MangoResponse<UserModel>) => {
    console.log(users);
});
```

But `users` is undefined, altough the filter `{ selector: { type: "User" } }` works well in Project Fauxton.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [nano documentation](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#getting-started):

> In nano the callback function receives always three arguments:
>
> 1. err - The error, if any.
> 2. body - The HTTP response body from CouchDB, if no error. JSON parsed body, binary for non JSON responses.
> 3. header - The HTTP response header from CouchDB, if no error.

Therefore, in the case of `db.find` you will have:

```
db.find(query, (err, body, header) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error thrown: ', err.message);
        return;
    }
    console.log('HTTP header received: ', header)
    console.log('HTTP body received: ', body)
});
```

I **didn't** work with `typescript`, however I think you can do the same with `typescript`.